# How do I interpret a monster stat block's attack line?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage, attack

I am running a game of D&D 5e. I am using an app to determine how a bandit does his attack against our group of players. The app says this in the bandit's statblock:

> ***Scimitar.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +3 to hit, reach 5 feet., one target. *Hit:* 5 (1d8+1) piercing damage."

What I'm confused about is how much damage the bandit does on his d8 roll (assuming he beats my group's AC on his d20 roll). Do I add the +3 to hit, d8+1, and the 5 sitting outside the () or what...?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. There are have been several versions of D&D, each with fairly different rules. Can you tell us which edition you're asking about?

Comment: This a takes place in 5e

Comment: Thank you for your help I now understand the meaning of the attack. Have a good day.